# How do I solve this maddening File Explorer visual glitch in Windows 10 when using the dark theme?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, nvidia-quadro

Every single time I open File Explorer or switch to a File Explorer window, it first paints several frames of the white background before it paints the actual, dark background. This appears to the naked eye as a very sharp, annoying "flash" effect. If you experience this 56 billion times a day, it slowly drives you insane... And it's driven me insane. I cannot express in words how much this bothers me, especially since this is a new computer whose entire "new computer" phase has been ruined by this.

The same thing happens for cmd.exe windows, but ***NOT*** for Firefox, Notepad++, or even Microsoft's own "Calculator". It seems to basically happen only with File Explorer and cmd.exe. And out of those two, only the File Explorer one truly bothers.

What could be causing it? How do I fix it? I've searched so long and hard but find absolutely nothing. Not a single mention of anyone else having this, much less how to solve it.

Please note that, even though it obviously is not due to the graphics drivers (since only specific programs have this issue), I have ***NUMEROUS*** times tried uninstalling the GPU drivers, rebooted, installed the new ones (and even old/stable ones), both from HP's site and NVIDIA's. I have made extremely sure that they are the correct ones. I have tried various random "tricks" suggested, but nothing has solved this whatsoever.

It's as if this bug is part of Windows 10. winver.exe says "1903". I did not have that version of Windows 10 on the previous computer, where I did not have this issue. So maybe it's somehow related to version 1903 of Windows 10?

Either way, the damage has already been done. I can never like this computer after it has put me through this torture. Still, a solution would be highly appreciated to save what's left of my sanity.

PS: "Not using dark theme" is not an option. My eyes die even quicker if I enable that bright, glowing theme.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a windows bug, anyways there has been several windows patches since your version. Please go to setting and update, your device may get unpatched viruses if you dont update (remember always update!)